scipy.linalg.sqrtm not giving the exact matrix square root
I am using scipy.linalg.sqrtm to calculate the square root of a matrix for a larger program. When I am taking the square root of a matrix which is already a square of another matrix, I am not getting the original matrix back.
So when I am implementing the following code snippet:
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

A = np.array([[1, 2], 
              [3, 4]])

B = A@A # Or A.dot(A)

C = sp.linalg.sqrtm(B)

I am getting the output as
C = array([[1.5666989 , 1.74077656],
       [2.61116484, 4.17786374]])

But shouldn't the matrix square root of C give back the matrix A?
Also when I do:
C@C

I get the output matrix as that of B.
array([[ 7., 10.],
       [15., 22.]])

I have tried with other random matrix combinations as well. Why is this happening? Is there a better way to calculate the square root of a matrix?

Matrix sqrt is not unique https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_2_by_2_matrix
